# How to copy data from one dataframe to another without altering column and rownames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the below table

```
  A B C
D 1 2 3
E 4 5 6
F 6 7 8
```

After fit_transform(), and converting back to dataframe, I get the below table

```
 0   1   2
0 v1  v2 v3
1 v4  v5 v5
2 v6  v7 v8
```

v1-v8 some normalised values.

But I want to retain my column and row names while doing fit_transform/after converting to dataframes. I'm not getting how to do that. Please help.

Comment: Give the columns and index from your initial dataframe to the dataframe constructor when you convert back

Comment: please share the code for the `fit_transform()`

Comment: Woud you be able to provide the dataFrame  fit_transform ?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning column and index of the original df to the new one by:

```
out_df.columns = df.columns
out_df.index = df.index
```

`df` is the original dataframe;
`out_df` is the dataframe after fit_transform()

Note : This will work if the cell order of the dataframe i.e. rows and column are in the same order as that of original `df`